# How skip id's from parent table on base of child table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

```
table1  

ides    name

1001    AA
1002    BB
1003    CC


table2      

ides    posi    cwawr

1001    2   xyz
1001    4   lmn
1001    6   abc
1002    2   ijk
1002    4   lmo
1002    6   pqr
1003    2   xyz
1003    4   sfs
```

in both above table i want to select the all ides of table1 where the posi not equal to 2 and cwawr not equal to xyz. for example 1001 posi has 2 and cwawr has xyz so this id should be skip. same 1003 also have posi value 2 and cwawr has xyz so it also should be skip.

so in result it should be

```
1002
```

only.

Thanks in advance,
Eshwer

Answer (score 4):

Classic NOT EXISTS (a.k.a. more formally "[anti semi join](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/19/671712.aspx)" and [relationally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28relational_algebra%29#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29))

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Table1 T1
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM
         Table2 T2
       WHERE
         T2.posi = 2 AND T2.cwawr = 'xyz'
         AND
         T2.ides = T1.ides)
```